# Add multiple y-axis to SAPUI5 VizFrame Column Charts

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

How can I add multiple y-axis to a Stacked Column Chart from SAPUI5 VizFrame?

I'm only able to find the `dual_stacked_column` vizType that I can use, which adds two columns for each dimension. I need to have three in my case.

```
<viz:feeds>
    <vizFeeds:FeedItem uid="valueAxis" type="Measure" values='Milk Current Year,Sugar Current Year,Tea Current Year'/>
    <vizFeeds:FeedItem uid="valueAxis2" type="Measure" values='Milk Previous Year,Sugar Previous Year,Tea Previous Year'/>
    <vizFeeds:FeedItem uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="Quarter"/>
</viz:feeds>
```

It's not possible to simply add a third one, as that's being ignored:

```
    <vizFeeds:FeedItem uid="valueAxis3" type="Measure" values='New Value'/>
```

This is programmed using the XML View until now, but JS View is no problem either, as long as there's a solution.

[image: My current result (need three columns for each Quarter)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With normal (non_stacked) columns it is possible in UI5 to have 3 columns per category.
With stacked_columns it is not possible, a “Triple_Stacked_Column” is currently not available.

Comment: Right, understand. Appreciate you having a look. I hope we can have a Triple, or rather a Multiple Stacked Column soon! :)

Answer (score 0):

We are looking into it if it is possible to use a third column here.

With the dual_stacked_column you have the blue y-axis title on the very left and the green y-axis title on the very right.
This might be a problem with a third column.
Would it be a quick workaround, if you use normal stacked_column and label the x-axis in a different way like
e.g. Q1-Current Year, Q1-Previous Year, Q1-New Year, Q2-Current Year, Q2-Previous Year, Q2-New Year, … ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought of this workaround too, but it doesn't work in this case. 

I need to have three Y columns within the same object, Q1 for example, because I have three separate pieces of information that need to go in there. Otherwise I'd need to create new chart for every Q1, Q2, Q3 where I can have what you've suggested, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: By the way, definitely interested in your findings about the possibility of adding a third column! Do you have an idea when we can expect some feedback on this? Thanks for looking into it!